# How to structure bson.D{}

Tags: mongodb, go, bson

I am trying to do an update query like so:

```
    coll = client.Database("tedi").Collection("users")

    filter := bson.D{primitive.E{Key: "_id", Value: userID}}
    update := bson.D{primitive.E{Key: "$addToSet", Value: bson.D{primitive.E{Key: "listings", Value: listingID}}}}
    
    ur, err := coll.UpdateOne(context.TODO(), filter, update)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    fmt.Println(ur.MatchedCount)
    fmt.Println(ur.UpsertedCount)
    fmt.Println(ur.ModifiedCount)
    fmt.Println(ur.UpsertedID)
```

I get no error back, but no update happens whatsoever so I suppose the `update` option is not well structured.
If I structure it like so: `bson.D{{"$addToSet", bson.D{{"listings", listingID}}}}` as it is recommended by the documentation here: https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Collection.UpdateOne the IDE is giving me a warning: `go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive.E composite literal uses unkeyed fields`

all `ur.*Count` variables are 0 and `ur.UpsertedID` is nil

I am using go1.15 Linux/amd64
and go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver v1.4.0

Comment: If `ur.MatchedCount` is `0`, that means your filter did not match any document, it's not an issue with the update document.

Comment: I thought of that but the IDs match, I mean the one my database and the one I use to query with

Comment: You _think_ they match, but if the `MatchedCount` is `0`, they _obviously_ don't. Try to provide a [mcve] (provide example documents and the Go `UserID`).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I found my problem.
I had to pass a `primitive.ObjectID` instead of a `string`.
And I did it like so:

```
    oid, err := primitive.ObjectIDFromHex(userID)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    filter := bson.D{primitive.E{Key: "_id", Value: oid}}
```

The rest is the same